# Select datas and fieldname from multiple tables based on same id

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have tried to find the best solution for my "problem" but my SQL knowledge is limited so I'm asking for your help.

I currently have a "main" table named Project and its primary key (ProjectId) is use in other tables like "Description" (see below)

```
Table "Project" :
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| ProjectId | P_Field1 | P_Field2  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1         | val1     | val2      |
+-----------+----------+-----------+

Table "Descriptive" :
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| ProjectId | D_Field1 | D_Field2  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1         | valA     | valB      |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that selects all the datas with its fieldname of multiple tables, based on a "ProjectId", then the output result would be :

```
Sotred Procedure Result with parameter @ProjectId = 1 :
+-----------+----------+
| FieldName | Value    |
+-----------+----------+
| P_Field1  | val1     |
+-----------+----------+
| P_Field2  | val2     |
+-----------+----------+
| D_Field1  | valA     |
+-----------+----------+
| D_Field2  | valB     |
+-----------+----------+
```

A friend told me that the SQL "PIVOT" function could help me but I never have used this function and my search on it really didn't help me because it is often used with "SUM", "MAX" etc and I don't need that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`unpivot`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), not `pivot`, and a `union`

```
select fieldname, value from [project] 
unpivot (value for fieldname in ([p_field1],[p_field2])) p
where projectid=1
union all
select fieldname, value from [descriptive] 
unpivot (value for fieldname in ([d_field1],[d_field2])) p
where projectid=1
```